# Windows Explorer like controls in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Does any one knows that if there's any build in or 3rd party control that provides a windows explorer like behavior?  Like Tile layout, Details layout， List layout and so on?

[image]

Comment: There are lots of shell specific tree and list controls. These are controls that understand the shell namespace and can populate themselves. Delphi ships with some in the samples folders. There are also the Turbo Power Shell Shock components. Also lots of SO questions on this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The types of views you are asking about are available in the standard TListView. Set the style property to vsReport, vsList, vsIcon or vsSmallIcon to get the desired effect. The ListView also supports a header row in vsReport by adding named columns through the Column property.

The functionality provided by windows explorer through its menu, address and search bar and left pane, is something you would have to add yourself.

Comment: Thanks Marjan,  that's the answer exactly I want.

Comment: Indeed, the `TListView` is merely a wrapper for the standard Windows LISTVIEW control, which is used everywhere in Explorer. (BTW, you might be interested in my breadcrumb bar control: http://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/controls/breadcrumb/readme.html)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Cool stuff!

Comment: @Andreas, Windows Vista's (and at least also Windows 7', don't have Windows 8 to check) Explorer uses some special sort of list view control (at least I don't know about animated group collapse/expand in standard list view control), which is not the `SysListView32` class nor listen to the list view control messages like before. So it's not the standard Windows list view control anymore...

Comment: @TLama: OK, I see, I'm sorry. But somehow I miss the times when Windows was simple. There was only the desktop and the common controls.

Answer (score 6):

The ShellBrowser Delphi components by Jam Software provide this with minimal programming:
[JamShellBrowser](http://www.jam-software.com/shellbrowser_delphi/samples.shtml). Costs but I have experienced excellent support. Supports IDE from Delphi 7 (+64bit in XE2). XE3 version due for release any day.

But then depends on what you want to do.  No additional Costs Option - Check the demos or samples folder in your Delphi install Ie as example locations:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ShellControls
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Samples\Delphi\VCL\ShellControls
```

Includes ShellComboBox, ShellListView, ShellTreeView and ShellChangeNotifier